# It's possible to export a survey on LimeSurvey throug API (remote control)?

Tags: php, api, remote-control, limesurvey, lime-unittest

it's possible to export a survey on LimeSurvey by API? I found a command to import (import_survey) but not for import.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not currently possible but feel free to extend the RemoteControl API if you are a coder and contribute back to the LimeSurvey project.